Doctrine DB Migration that matches existing DB Setup
I have a Database that was created in a Node App with Sequilize.
I am moving the whole app from node to php 8.3 and Symfony 6.4 + doctrine.
When trying to adapt the entities to Doctrine and run the migrations Doctrine is recreating some fields and also the FK. I want to avoid this to happen but I am not sure what else I should be doing...
The Entities in the NodeApp looks like this:
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class CognitoUser extends Model {
        static associate (models) {
            CognitoUser.belongsTo(models.UserProfile, {
                foreignKey: 'userProfileUuid',
                onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
                onDelete: 'RESTRICT'
            });
        }
...
CognitoUser.init({
        UserPoolId: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        Username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        UserEmail: DataTypes.STRING,
        UserCreateDate: DataTypes.DATE,
        UserLastModifiedDate: DataTypes.DATE,
        UserStatus: DataTypes.STRING,
        Enabled: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        // MixedCase for Cognito native, camelCase for everything else
        customSwitchToEmailFlow: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        cognitoSyncedAt: DataTypes.DATE,
        userProfileUuid: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, { sequelize, modelName: 'CognitoUser', tableName: 'CognitoUser', timestamps: false });
    return CognitoUser;

the UserProfile entity looks like this:
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class UserProfile extends Model {
        static associate (models) {
            UserProfile.hasOne(models.CognitoUser, { foreignKey: 'userProfileUuid' }); // -> CognitoUser kriegt ne Spalte
            UserProfile.belongsTo(models.CoreCustomer, {
                foreignKey: 'coreCustomerUuid'
            });
            UserProfile.hasMany(models.UserProductRole, { foreignKey: 'userProfileUuid' });
        }
    }
    UserProfile.init({
        uuid: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
        }
    }, { sequelize, modelName: 'UserProfile', tableName: 'UserProfile' });
    return UserProfile;
};

The tables that are being generated by the Sqlize migration look like this:

CREATE TABLE `CognitoUser` (
  `UserPoolId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `UserEmail` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UserCreateDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `UserLastModifiedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `UserStatus` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Enabled` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cognitoSyncedAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `userProfileUuid` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `customSwitchToEmailFlow` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserPoolId`,`Username`),
  KEY `userProfileUuid` (`userProfileUuid`),
  CONSTRAINT `CognitoUser_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userProfileUuid`) REFERENCES `UserProfile` (`uuid`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


and the UserProfile Table:
CREATE TABLE `UserProfile` (
  `uuid` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `coreCustomerUuid` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`),
  KEY `coreCustomerUuid` (`coreCustomerUuid`),
  CONSTRAINT `UserProfile_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`coreCustomerUuid`) REFERENCES `CoreCustomer` (`uuid`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


The entities in Doctrine are defined like this:
#[ORM\Entity]
#[ORM\Table(name:"CognitoUser")]
#[ORM\Index(name: 'userProfileUuid', columns: ['userProfileUuid'])]
class CognitoUser
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: "string", length: 255)]
    private string $UserPoolId;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type:"string", length: 255)]
    private string $Username;

    #[ORM\Column(type:"string", length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $UserEmail = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?DateTime $UserCreateDate = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?DateTime $UserLastModifiedDate = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $UserStatus = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    private ?bool $Enabled = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: "boolean", nullable: true)]
    private ?bool $customSwitchToEmailFlow = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    private ?DateTime $cognitoSyncedAt = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: UserProfile::class, inversedBy: 'cognitoUsers')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(
        name:"userProfileUuid",
        referencedColumnName: "uuid",
        nullable: false,
        columnDefinition: "CHAR(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL"
    )]
    private ?UserProfile $userProfileUuid = null;

and the UserProfile Entity looks like this:
#[ORM\Entity]
class UserProfile
{
    use DefaultEntityPropertiesTrait;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(
        type: "string",
        length: 36,
        options: ["fixed"=>true],
        columnDefinition: "CHAR(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL"
    )]
    private ?string $uuid = null;

    /**
     * @var Collection<int, CognitoUser>
     */
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: CognitoUser::class, mappedBy: 'userProfileUuid')]
    private Collection $cognitoUsers;

    /**
     * @var Collection<int, UserProductRole>
     */
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: UserProductRole::class, mappedBy: 'userProfileUuid')]
    private Collection $userProductRoles;


    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'userProfiles')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "coreCustomerUuid", referencedColumnName: "uuid", nullable: true)]
    private ?CoreCustomer $coreCustomerUuid = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cognitoUsers = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->userProductRoles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

I have also made this changes in doctrine.yaml file:
doctrine:
    dbal:
    ...
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_bin


When running the command make:migration I am getting the following which I am trying to avoid:
Up section:
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE CognitoUser DROP FOREIGN KEY CognitoUser_ibfk_1');
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE CognitoUser CHANGE userProfileUuid userProfileUuid CHAR(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL');
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE CognitoUser ADD CONSTRAINT FK_60B8CF0DD034F61E FOREIGN KEY (userProfileUuid) REFERENCES UserProfile (uuid)');

Down section:
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE CognitoUser DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_60B8CF0DD034F61E');
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE CognitoUser CHANGE userProfileUuid userProfileUuid CHAR(36) NOT NULL COLLATE `utf8mb4_bin`');
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE CognitoUser ADD CONSTRAINT CognitoUser_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (userProfileUuid) REFERENCES UserProfile (uuid) ON UPDATE CASCADE');


Does it lead to a change? Could you pleas provice the down section

you can remove query manually from your migration file than execute migration command
